# Change owner on NFS share

Tags: linux, apache, redhat, nfs, chown

I have a NFS share mounted on my redhat server but now I need to change the owner so apache can access it.

chown -R apache:apache /folder

doesn't work.

Anyone tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to take look at the below reference

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-nfs-storage-for-apache-lighttpd-nginx-webserver.html

and modify your configuration accordingly

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpfull link. I created the user apache on the NFS server and gave it the right groupid and now he is the owner of the NFS share and it works!